# Cron job on google app engine only five days of a week

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I am setting up a cron job app engine, which has to be executed on Mon, Tue, wed, Thu, Fri between some time.

According to [Cron job doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron) i can make a syntax like this,

**every monday, tueday, wednesday, thursday, friday 30 minutes from 9:00 to 15:45** (in schedule tag)

can you please validate the same.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cronref#schedule_format

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are only able to specify which days to run on when specifying an exact time to run. You cannot mix intervals and days: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cronref#schedule_format

What I would do is schedule the cron to run from 9:00 to 15:45 every day like this:

```
every 30 minutes from 9:00 to 15:45
```

And, then add some code in your handler that exits early if it is Saturday or Sunday.